# How to set Placeholder and PlaceHolder Color in Editor Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to set **Placeholder Text** and **Placeholder Color** in `Editor` in **Xamarin Forms**.

It has no default Functionality or Properties how to customize it?

**Reference documentation :** [Xamarin Forms Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a custom renderer for that (Here is the Android Custom Renderer) you will need another renderer for iOS:

```
public class PlaceholderEditor : Editor
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<PlaceholderEditor, string>(view => view.Placeholder, String.Empty);

    public PlaceholderEditor()
    {
    }

    public string Placeholder
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public class PlaceholderEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public PlaceholderEditorRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(
        ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var element = e.NewElement as PlaceholderEditor;
            this.Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(
        object sender,
        PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == PlaceholderEditor.PlaceholderProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var element = this.Element as PlaceholderEditor;
            this.Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the color you may need something like this (Android):

```
Control.SetHintTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
```

There already a thread for this in the Xamarin Forums:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20616/placeholder-editor

And more about Custom Renderers information below:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Comment: For Native Ios?

Answer (score 1):

Set the placeholder string to your Editor's Text in Xaml
Then in Code behind file:

```
InitializeComponent();

var placeholder = myEditor.Text;

myEditor.Focused += (sender, e) =>
{
     // Set the editor's text empty on focus, only if the place 
     // holder is present
     if (myEditor.Text.Equals(placeholder))
     {
          myEditor.Text = string.Empty;
          // Here You can change the text color of editor as well
          // to active text color
     }
};

myEditor.Unfocused += (sender, e) => 
{
     // Set the editor's text to place holder on unfocus, only if 
     // there is no data entered in editor
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myEditor.Text.Trim()))
    {
        myEditor.Text = placeholder;
        // Here You can change the text color of editor as well
        // to dim text color (Text Hint Color)
    }
};
```