# How to change the Text color of placeholder in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, placeholder

Is it possible to change the Text color of part of the placeholder.

```xml
<Controls:BorderlessEntry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                          x:Name="ABS_ID"
                          Placeholder="Enter Name Here *"/>
```

I want to change the asterisk "*" Color to red and rest of the text will have default color.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572150/how-to-set-placeholder-and-placeholder-color-in-editor-xamarin-forms

Comment: You can't partially change the color of placeholder text of entry, "PlaceholderColor" property will apply to whole text of placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following workaround:

Wrap an `Entry` and a `Label` into a `StackLayout`. And make the `StackLayout` like an Entry with placeholder.

The code is like this:

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Entry x:Name="ABS_ID" 
           Text="Enter Name Here     "
           HorizontalOptions="Start" 
           Focused="OnEntryFocused" 
           Unfocused="OnEntryUnFocused"/>
    <Label x:Name="ABS_ID2" 
           Text="*" 
           TextColor="Red" 
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           Margin="-20"/>
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    bool showPlaceHolder = true;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void OnEntryFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (showPlaceHolder) {
            ABS_ID.Text = "";
            ABS_ID2.Text = "";
        }
    }
    void OnEntryUnFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((ABS_ID.Text == "") && (ABS_ID2.Text == ""))
        {
            ABS_ID.Text = "Enter Name Here ";
            ABS_ID2.Text = "*";
            showPlaceHolder = true;
        }
        else {
            showPlaceHolder = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image: screenshot of the result]